# keychain-access-group entitlement not updating

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning, code-signing-entitlements

The provisioning profiles for my apps that come down from Apple have the keychain-access-groups entitlement turned on.  My local Xcode does *not* have this entitlement (capability) turned on.  This is resulting in local entitlements that don't match those available in the provisioning profile's entitlements and my adhoc distributed builds are not installing in our devices.

To make matters worse, I am working with multiple bundle ids within the same target (using scheme and config modifications.  Not ideal, I know), so when I go to muck with the capabilities tab, it's unclear which App ID I'm editing.

I have temporarily overridden the bundle id, so *I know* which app id is being edited via the capabilities tab.  But, nothing I'm doing seems to edit the provisioning profiles available via the dev portal.  Nothing gets invalidated.  (I see the local entitlements file being edited immediately just fine)

I'm using Xcode 7 (7.3.1).

I've tried restarting Xcode.  I also tried running on a local device (checking and unchecking the capability) hoping that would update the used provisioning profile.  Still no change seen in the dev portal.

*UPDATE*

Later that same day, checking/unchecking the capability started showing network activity spinners within Xcode and the dev portal started updating immediately (provisioning profiles were invalidated).  *However*, the next day, managing a different app, back to the same issue where I'm not seeing any updates in the dev portal.

How do I edit this entitlement consistently?